# Condition evaluating unexpectedly

Tags: bash, shell

i am trying to write a simple bash script for a custom screensaver, i want simple to go the screen black if in idle, and go back to normal if not.

```
#!/bin/bash
#sets display gamma very low, for screensaver purposes


idle=false
idle_after=3000 #in milliseconds

while true; do

#if system is idle
if [[ idle_now=$(xprintidle) -gt "$idle_after" && "$idle"=false ]]  ;then

echo "1"

        `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --brightness  0.01`
        idle=true

fi

if  [[ idle_now=$(xprintidle) -lt "$idle_after" && "$idle"=true ]] ; then
echo "2"
        `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --brightness  1`  #set screen back to normal
         exit
fi


done
```

i really don't know why the second if query gets executed first.
i thought the idle variable is initialized "false" at startup 
can someone explain this to me ? and if someone has improvements to give on my approach i 'would very appreciate that , thanks

Comment: There are some basic issues with your script that would be identified by http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: In addition to the problems in the conditionals, why do you have backquotes around the `xrandr` commands? That takes the commands' output (if any) and tries to execute it as a command... and I don't think that's how `xrandr` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test expressions are wrong.

The reason for 2nd `if` was executed first is that there are no spaces between operands and operators inside test (`[[` and `]]`).

For better understanding, let's see a possible variable substitution in the first loop assuming that `xprintidle` returns `10`:

```
[[ idle_now=$(xprintidle) -lt "$idle_after" && "$idle"=true ]]
# becomes
[[ idle_now=10 -lt 3000 && false=true ]]
```

Now you wanted compare 10 against 3000, but now you're comparing the string `"idle_now=10"` against `3000`. As any string is converted to zero if the characters are not digits, its like you did:

```
[[ 0 -lt 3000 && false=true ]]
# that becomes
[[ <true> && false=true ]]
```

Now, the second operand is also one string "false=true" (not a comparison), and any string converted to boolean is false when it's empty. That's not your case, the string has 10 characters, so it's evaluated to true.

```
[[ <true> && <true> ]]
# that becomes
<true>
```

*Note: I used `<true>` and `<false>` just to clarify, they really are internal representation of boolean values.*

**Fixing it**

I imagine `idle_now` was meant to be a variable that it's never used, so we'll ignore it.

So the if expressions should be:

```
[[ "$(xprintidle)" -gt "$idle_after" && "$idle" = false ]]
# and
[[ "$(xprintidle)" -lt "$idle_after" && "$idle" = true ]]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, so it is right to say: in an if expression the '=' without spaces means allocation, and with spaces -> comparison ?

Comment: No, without spaces just mean a string like any other: Ex. `[[ a=1 ]]` is equal to `[[ "a=1" ]]`, which is converted to <true>, because it's not an empty string. To assign a variable you have to do it outside of  `[[ ]]` or inside a bash expression like `((a=1))`.